# Swift + C mapping

Tags: swift

I have this struct in C

```
struct connect_arg {
    char dest_ip[50];
    unsigned int dest_port;
    char id[MAX_ID_LEN];
    char psk[MAX_PSK_LEN];
    float devicenum;
}
```

I'm trying to use it in swift, but the mapping I get is something like

```
var co = connect_arg(dest_ip: (Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8), dest_port: UInt32, id: (Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8), psk: (Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8), device_lat: Float, device_lon: Float)
```

As you can see, that's a lot of Int8...

Maybe the problem is because the fixed size array in C which aren't supported in Swift ?

What can I do ?

Comment: Indeed, fixed size arrays are not supported in Swift--as such, they are imported as tuples.

Comment: so, any idea how can i fill this struct ?

Comment: 1) In C, you should use `stdint.h` types for fixed-width types - much like swift does 2) Even for IPv6, 50 octets are too much for an IP. 3) The question is not about C, but about swift.

Comment: If you have a C struct, what about using C functions for initialization and operations?

Comment: I need to fill this struct and send it to a c function.
Can I add objective-c files to the project that will somehow create and fill this struct and send it to the c function from there?

Comment: for now, the workaround with objective c seems OK